# Google Cloud VPN maintenance

Tags: vpn, gcp

I would like to check when my **GCP Cloud VPN** underwent to maintenance.
I found docs regarding [Cloud VPN Maintenance and availability](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview#vpn-maintenance-cycles), but there is noting about checking when this event occurred.

Is it possible to check this type of events in the logs?